# Probability that the team will win the tournament.

Tags: probability

There are only 4 teams left in the tournament, and they are in the semifinals. Team A i playing against team B, and team C is playing against team D. So if team A wins against team B he will play either with team C or team D.

The probabilities of each team beating other team is given in the table:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   Teams   |     A     |     B     |     C     |     D     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     A     |     x     |    0.2    |    0.3    |    0.4    |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     B     |           |     x     |    0.5    |    0.6    |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     C     |           |           |     x     |    0.7    |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     D     |           |           |           |     x     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

(You read the table as probability of team A beating team B is 0.2, beating team C is 0.3, etc.)

The question is find the probability that team A will win the tournament.

Is this just $$p(A) = 0.2*0.3 + 0.2*0.4 = 0.14$$

Comment: You  aren't taking into account the probable result of the C-D game.

Comment: @saulspatz Like this(lets say P(AxB) means the probability that A beats B): $$p(A) = p(AxB)*(p(AxC)*p(CxD) + p(AxD)*p(DxC)) = 0.2*(0.3*0.7 + 0.4*0.3) = 0.066$$

Comment: That looks better.